# Cannot import Musixmatch library in python

Tags: python, api, import, musixmatch

cannot import Musixmatch

I am having error when using Musixmatch API tool when running code below

```
from musixmatch import Musixmatch
musixmatch = Musixmatch('9173cdafb8c897fc5417ea88d8d0bba8')
```

Error is as below

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[51], line 1
----> 1 from musixmatch import Musixmatch
      2 musixmatch = Musixmatch('~~~~')

ImportError: cannot import name 'Musixmatch' from 'musixmatch' (C:\Users\---\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\musixmatch\__init__.py)
#api key hidden
```

I referred to this website https://github.com/hudsonbrendon/python-musixmatch
What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Run `pip list | grep musixmatch`. Do you see `musixmatch` or `pymusixmatch`? If `pymusixmatch` does not show up then try installing `pymusixmatch` by running `pip install pymusixmatch`. I ran this locally and it worked.